# "Да кто ты? Да ты кто такой?" - состав сказуемых

Tags: сказуемые

Из книги Бабайцевой и Чесноковой "Русский Язык. Теория. 5-9 классы", раздел 173, "Составное именное сказуемое":

> Реже именная часть выражается числительными и местоимениями:
>   Пять плюс пять будет десять. ("пять плюс пять" - подл., "будет десять" - сказ.)
>   Да **кто ты**? ("кто ты" - сказуемое)
>   Да ты **кто такой**? ("ты" - подлежащее, "кто такой" - сказуемое)
>
> Полная цитата: "Да кто ты?.. Да ты кто такой?" (А. Чехов) - (*подчеркнуты сказуемые*)

Почему в одном случае "ты" - часть сказуемого, а в другом - подлежащее? А если изменить порядок слов:

- "Да **кто ты такой**?"

все равно "ты" будет подлежащим?

А если убрать "такой" и поменять порядок:

- "Да **ты кто**?"

сказуемое будет "ты кто"?

---

P.S. Местоимение "кто" - это вспомогательная часть?

P.P.S. Отрывок из учебника:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Да кто ты такой?  Ты - подлежащее, кто такой - именная часть составного именного сказуемого.

Дуплексив  "такой" входит в состав сказуемого, но при этом согласуется с подлежащим "ты" (кто она такая, кто они такие).

Да кто ты?  Ты - подлежащее, кто  - именная часть составного именного сказуемого.

Частица ДА употр. для придания высказыванию большей силы, выразительности.

Comment: Спасибо! Наверное, в учебнике очепятка..

Answer (score 3):

> Да **кто ты**? ("кто ты" - сказуемое)

Нет. Сказуемое здесь -- **кто**, а **ты** -- подлежащее.

Comment: Тогда либо ваше мнение расходится с позицией Бабайцевой, либо в учебнике опечатка. Двойной линией там подчеркнуто "**кто ты**"..

Comment: _CopperKettle: "...либо в учебнике опечатка"._ === Да, в учебнике опечатка.